# Possible Boolean functions in n-dimensional space

Tags: functions, boolean-algebra

> Each unique assignment of 0-1 values to the $2^n$ possible inputs in $n$ dimensions represents a Boolean function. Therefore, in $n$ dimensions, there are $2^{2^n}$ such unique assignments that can be made, and this $2^{2^n}$ possible functions.

Why are there $2^{2^n}$ such unique assignments not $2\cdot2^{n}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You have $2^n$ distinct possible "inputs" to the function: indeed, $\lvert \{0,1\}^n\rvert = 2^n$.
- For each input $x\in\{0,1\}^n$, the value of a Boolean function $f$ is either $0$ or $1$, i.e. there are two choices for $f(x)$.

Overall, you therefore have $$(\text{number of choices})^{(\text{number of inputs})} = 2^{2^n}$$ different Boolean functions on $\{0,1\}^n$.

*One way to see it is that the choice for each "input" is independent from the choice of the others. You chose the value for the first input: 2 choices. Then you choose for the second one: 2 choices as well, no matter what you had chosen for the first input. That means you have $2^2=4$ possibilities for the value on the first two choices: $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, and $(1,1)$. And so on: the number of choices for the $k$ first inputs is $2^k$, and overall for $k=2^n$ you get the result.*

---

*Note that this is not specific to Boolean functions: if $A,B$ are two sets (let's say finite for simplicity), then the number of functions from $A$ to $B$ is $\lvert B\rvert^{\lvert A\rvert}$.*

Comment: Sorry I am still confused. Here's where I am stuck. So I want to count all set of mappings from input to output. I think 2^4 will cover all of them (0,0,0->0),(0,0,0->1),(0,0,1->0),(0,0,0->1)...

Comment: I don't understand the notation above. What is the domain (i.e., $n=?$) in your comment?

Comment: thanks again! ok, so I don't why you are mapping a set of inputs to 0-1 instead each input to 0-1. If possible can you have a look at the 3^rd para( In B^n) from here(https://books.google.co.in/books/reader?id=4lNG2BGU-osC&printsec=frontcover&output=reader&pg=GBS.PA78).

Comment: You have $2^n$ differents inputs "$x$" in the domain (Do you agree?). A Boolean function $f$ is defined by the list of all values $f(x)$ (one per $x$ in the domain), so it is defined by a list of $2^n$ values in $\{0,1\}$ (Are you OK with that?). So there are as many functions $f\colon\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}$ as there are lists of $2^n$ elements with entries in $\{0,1\}$, i.e. the number of distinct binary strings of length $2^n$ (still OK?). This number is $\lvert \{0,1\}^{2^n}\rvert = 2^{2^n}$ (OK?). (If something is confusing you, where do you start having trouble?)

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia (Are you still confused, or did the above clear up your doubts?)

Comment: thank for the reply. The place where I am confused is that there are $2^n$ inputs. I think they are $n$ inputs.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia No, there are $2^n$. Each string $x\in\{0,1\}^n$ is an input. Take as example $n=3$: you have $000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111$, that is $8=2^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, It's from Neural Networks- A classroom Approach By Satish Kumar. Chapter 4. Geometry of Binary Threshold Neurons 4.3 Space of a Boolean Function.
Here in Range Set you have only 2 Answers i.e. either 0 or 1, And for n=2, you have 4 different choices [0,1] x [0,1] (i.e. Cartesian product of two closed intervals.) {00,01,10,11}. 
So **Your answer is always in 0 or 1** Because it's a Boolean Function so....
Always f: 2^n -> 2. 
 NOT LIKE f:2^n -> 2^m.
Just as earlier mentioned by Clement it's 
(No of Choices)^ 2^n.